# Delete File from Jlist

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

Don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to delete the selected file from my directory but it's only deleting it from the list. Thanks

```
  private void deletecustButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) customerList.getModel();

    int selectedIndex = customerList.getSelectedIndex();
    File customer = new File("Customers/" + selectedIndex);
    if (selectedIndex != 1) {
      customer.delete();
      model.remove(selectedIndex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What type of data is in the list?  Also, you really should inspect the return result from `File#delete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int selectedIndex = customerList.getSelectedIndex();
```

I doubt you want to get the selectedIndex().

I would think you want to get the selected value:

```
String fileName = customerList.getSelectedValue().toString();
File customer = new File("Customers/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete several selected files of the list with one click:

```
private void deletecustButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String fileName;
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) customerList.getModel();
    // Get the number of selected files 
    // (corresponding of the size of the int[] customerList.getSelectedIndices() ).
    int numberOfSelections = customerList.getSelectedIndices().length;
    int selectedIndex=0;
    File customer = null;
    // Loop to remove all selected items except your n#1 cust.
    // We begin at the end because the list will be "cut" each turn of the loop
    for(int i = numberOfSelections-1; i >=0 ; i--){
        // Get the selected index
        selectedIndex = customerList.getSelectedIndices()[i];
        if (selectedIndex != 1) {
            fileName = model.getElementAt(selectedIndex);
            customer = new File("Customers/" + fileName );
            customer.delete();
            model.remove(selectedIndex);
        }          
    }
  }
```